# Procedures in a database or in external jar in Derby

Tags: java, database, derby

[The document DerbySQLroutines](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbySQLroutines#Are_Derby_Procedures_.2AStored.2A_Procedures.3F) explains that Derby procedures can be either stored in a database, using SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR, or kept in an external JAR file.

What would be advantages of each approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's baked into the database, then the database is usable w/o extra jars. The disadvantage of that is that you'd have to go through the effort of getting the code into the database. It's sort of a pay now or pay later trade off.